# Not routing certain traffic through vpn

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, windows-networking

I use a vpn service and all my traffic gows through it when I'm connected to it. I like all data to go through it besides my database traffic. The database in running on a dedicated server remotely.

The vpn is being used on a windows machine. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume that the VPN connection is set up on the very machine you use and not on some uplink. Then you should run command line with admin privileges and type the following:

```
route add IP_OF_YOUR_DATABASE mask 255.255.255.255 IP_OF_YOUR_GATEWAY
```

This will make all the traffic sent to IP_OF_YOUR_DATABASE go through the normal gateway, bypassing your VPN connection.

For me it would be like:

```
route add 77.xx.xx.xx mask 255.255.255.255 192.168.0.1
```

192.168.0.1 is my router's address on my network.